# symfony 3 use 'strict' => true in email validation field

Tags: forms, symfony, validation, email

i want to add `'strict' => true` to email validation input in form building
https://symfony.com/doc/3.3/reference/constraints/Email.html#strict

why? because normal email validation allow invalid emails ex. `test@test` passed!

i tried but i get error `(The option "strict" does not exist. Defined options are: "action", "allow_extra_fields", "attr", ... )`

code like that:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) :void
{
     $builder
     ->add('name', TextType::class, [ 'label' => 'Name' ])
     ->add('email', EmailType::class, [
           'label' => 'Email', 
           'strict' => true ]  <<<<< not work
     )
     ->add('subject', ChoiceType::class, [ 'label' => 'Subject',
     ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to register validation constraints like below:

```
$builder
     ->add('name', TextType::class, [ 'label' => 'Name' ])
     ->add('email', EmailType::class, [
           'label' => 'Email', 
           'constraints' => array(
               new Email(array('strict'=>true)),
            )
       )
```

Comment: ok good, but email input still consider `test@test` as correct validate email! any idea?

Comment: you have to use custom pattern in this case. [Regex](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Regex.html)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to adding `'strict' => true` to `Email` the constraint options, there is also a setting in the Symfony framework config to enable it for all `Email` constraints by default. See [`strict_email` configuration in the Symfony docs v3.4](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/reference/configuration/framework.html#strict-email)

For Symfony >=4.1 the configuration option `strict_email` has been deprecated [so use `email_validation_mode` instead](https://symfony.com/doc/4.2/reference/configuration/framework.html#email-validation-mode)